# django cnotes not working

Tags: django

I have just installed [django-cnotes](http://github.com/SeanOC/django-cnotes)
But it wont work.
It just throws up this error

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 279, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 651, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)

File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 245, in __call__
response = middleware_method(request, response)

File "/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/django_cnote-0.3.4-py2.5.egg/cnotes/middleware.py", line 47, in process_response
signed_data = self.sign('cnotes', base64.urlsafe_b64encode(Pickle.dumps(cnotes.cnotes)))

PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>: attribute lookup django.utils.functional.__proxy__ failed
```

And it is not even in the normal django error debug page. What you see above is all there is on the screen.

And I have just used it as described on github, I just dont get it. Any one have an idea for what is causing this?

**UPDATE:**
Okay, so I have found something, I think.

```
message = _("You have successfully altered ")
message += edituser.username
cnotes.add(message)
message2 = _("You may now close ")
cnotes.add(message2)
```

This will cause the error. So I thought "Okay, I can only call it once per view" That would have been stupid and it was indeed not the cause.

The following code will produce no error

```
message = _("You have successfully altered ")
message += edituser.username
cnotes.add(message)
message2 = '_("You may now close ")'
cnotes.add(message2)
```

But is not because of the translation it uses that fine just 2 lines above, but it has to be something with doing another translation or something. Im lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though `pickle` is receiving an object of type `django.utils.functional.__proxy__`.  This means either your input is weird, or there is a bug in `cnotes`.

If there is something wrong with your input to `cnotes`, you should see it if you take a look at the types of your `message`s (I used the `manage.py shell`):

```
>>> message = _("You have successfully altered ")
>>> message += "Bob Knoblick"
>>> type(message)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> message2 = _("You may now close ")
>>> type(message2)
<type 'unicode'>
>>>
```

If your types come back as anything other than `unicode` or `str`, I'd dig into your code and figure out where that other type is coming from, or ensure that it [can be pickled](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

If there is something wrong within `cnotes`, you should get the same error doing this:

```
cnotes.add(u'Foo')
cnotes.add(u'Bar')
cnotes.add(u'Baz')
```

**Per the original author:**
The translated string, `_("You may now close ")` was not ending up as a unicode string.  One can use this to force unicode before sending to `cnotes`:

```
message2 = unicode(_("You may now close "))
```

Comment: That helped. Just filling in the solution for someone else to find, though it is dead simple (ofc).
When adding a User instance (or part of it) it turn the whole variable into unnicode, but I did not do that the second time around which is why I didn't catch it.

To recap: Convert translated objects into unicode or strings before sending them to cnotes.
I just did unicode(_("You may now close ")) and it worked fine.

Jack M. If you could add the solution to your answer I can mark it as accepted for the next newbie to find.
Many thanks